# Inequalities and $x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I would just like to clarify something in regards to inequality and how x^2 would affect it.

Why is it that if I have the inequality:
$x^2(x+5)(x-6)>0$, for example, I can simply divide out $x^2$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $x$ is real, then $x^2$ is either zero or positive. If $x^2$ is positive, then you can divide by it without reversing the inequality. If it is zero, then you cannot. However, in this case it's impossible for $x^2$ to be zero, because in that case $x^2(x+5)(x-6)$ would be zero, contrary to the stated inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $x^2 \geq 0$. The problem with dividing variables when manipulating inequalities is that you have two cases depending on whether the variable is positive or negative. In your example, 
$$x^2 (x+5)(x-6) >0 \Rightarrow (x+5)(x-6)>0$$
for the reason I just outlined, so you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because $x^2 \geq 0$ and in this case since $x=0$ is not a solution, $x^2 > 0$.

You can see it as this: If $x^2$ is positive, then $(x+5)(x-6)$ has to also be positive for the overall product to be positive.

Thus, we can divide the inequality by $x^2$ and yield that $(x+5)(x-6) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can only divide it out because $x^2(x+5)(x-6) \le 0$ in the neighbourhood of $x=0$. In general it is a bad idea to divide it out. For instance$$(x+5)(x-6) \lt 0 \implies x \in (-5,6)$$but $$x^2(x+5)(x-6) \lt 0 \implies x \in (-5,0)\cup(0,6)$$